# Why is it "need" in "it need not be thus" instead of "needs"?

Tags: modal-verbs, subject-verb-agreement, semi-modals

> But it need not be thus

This sentence boggles me. I expected to see "it needs not" or "it does not need to". What am I missing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is "modal *need*".  The English verb "need" can be used as a normal verb

> He needs a drink.  I don't need a break.

And as a normal verb it has normal grammar.  It is transitive and takes a direct object.

But *need* can also function as a modal verb, like "can" or "will". And modal verbs are defective.  Remember you say "He will not be..." and not *"He doesn't will be".

When "need" functions as a modal verb, it is the auxiliary and it doesn't take "s" in the third person.

> He need not be ...

Use of "need" as a modal verb is becoming less common in English, so this construction is formal and rather old-fashioned, it is almost never used in positive sentences.  It is being replaced by a catenive construction with a normal verb and a "to" infinitive

> It need not be thus.  → It does not need to be like that.

Comment: is this really a modal use, rather than a subjunctive?

Comment: @Tristan I'm not aware of any evidence that it's a subjunctive. This construction seems to work the same way as other modal verbs: he will not do it, he should not do it, he need not do it. The only difference from other modal verbs is that it's rarely if ever used without "not" (we say "he will do it" and "he should do it," but not "he need do it"). Also, present subjunctive verbs are usually negated by putting the word "not" _before_ them, as in "I propose that he not need to retake the exam before we give him a passing grade."

Comment: Even if it's rarer now, we needn't forget the old ways entirely.

Comment: No, it's not subjunctive.  We're not discussing the possibility that it need not be thus.  We're saying directly that it need not be thus, and therefore it has to be indicative.

Comment: I think you mean "modal verbs are *defective*"

Comment: ... though I have some recollection of quasi-Shakespearean "needs be"... in what I would have thought of as analogous contexts.

Comment: @Tanner-reinstateLGBTpeople  The Wikipedia Subjunctive page gives the example "I shall ensure that he leave immediately".

Comment: @Kaz  Yes, in that sentence the modal "shall" and the verb "ensure" are indicative, but the verb "leave" is subjunctive. As in the OP example, the modal verb "shall" wouldn't become "shalls" in the third person singular.

Comment: @paulgarrett  In "If needs be" the word "needs" is a plural noun, not a verb. (but "be" is in the subjunctive)

Comment: Aha!!! I'd never imagined that that "needs" was a noun! Very interesting. :) Thanks.